# intrinsic content size for NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nstextview

I'm subclassing NSTextView and using following code to calculate the intrinsic content size so that the height of the text view grows with it's content in my auto layout constraints.

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return [[self layoutManager] usedRectForTextContainer:[self textContainer]].size;
}
```

This works except on the initial call where it returns (0,0) for the size.

If I call `[self setNeedsLayout:YES]` in my view after creating the text view and invalidate the text view's content size in `-layout` it will return the correct size for the new empty text view.

Is there a way to have `-intrinsicContentSize` return the correct size for my new text view without updating my view's layout?

Comment: Call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`?

Comment: By the way, the usual way to make a text view grow with its content is to look at its `contentSize`, which is maintained for you automatically....

Comment: @matt That's what I'm doing in -layout which works but I don't understand why I have to do this in -layout the first time.  I invalidate the content size when the text changes which works fine.

Comment: @matt NSTextView doesn't have a contentSize property unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, because I'm so used to iOS that I naturally was thinking in terms of UITextView. Please ignore everything I said (except in order to have a good laugh later on).

Comment: If this _were_ iOS, my next suggestion would have been: is it possible that your "first time" is just too early? The text stack just isn't set up yet...?

Comment: That's where I got the idea to invalidate the intrinsic content size in -layout since this gets called after everything is setup.

Comment: Then it seems to me you have answered your own question (and that there's no problem).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469815), where Alexander Staubo shares a slightly adjusted version of your code. This works for me.