# NSTextView not properly resizing with auto layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I have a simple layout, which consists of NSView and its subview NSTextView.  NSTextView is programmatically filled with some text that spawns multiple lines.  I tie everything together using auto-layout (all done programmatically).  However, when everything is displayed NSTextView is cut off, only one line is showing.

After searching the web, the best answer I could find was:

[Using Autolayout with expanding NSTextViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237622/using-autolayout-with-expanding-nstextviews)

However, this only works if I manually change the text in NSTextView after everything is displayed (which is not really my use case).  The views are readjusted and the whole NSTextView is displayed.

I am trying to figure out when NSViewController is done with laying out subviews so that I could call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` on the NSTextView.  The equivalent of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in UIViewController.

Nothing I tried worked so far.  I attempted calling `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` for NSTextView:

- At the end of `loadView`
- After I filled NSTextView with my text

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After further research, found the answer:

1. Create custom `NSView` subclass that contains `NSTextView`
2. In `NSView` subclass override `layout` method that calls `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`

Also check out this link that explains subtleties of auto layout and intrinsic content size (among many other things):

http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html

Sample code:

```
@interface MyView : NSView
  @property MyTextView *textView;
@end

@implementation MyView

// init & create content & set constraints

-(void) layout {
    [super layout];
    [self.textView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

@end
```

Implementation of MyTextView:

```
@implementation MyTextView

- (NSSize) intrinsicContentSize {
    NSTextContainer* textContainer = [self textContainer];
    NSLayoutManager* layoutManager = [self layoutManager];
    [layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer: textContainer];
    return [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer: textContainer].size;
}

- (void) didChangeText {
    [super didChangeText];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

@end
```